# IE returns 304 using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching, xmlhttprequest

Here is the scenario:

I have a text box where I can enter a text for "Status". Beside it is a label that should contain the latest "Status". After entering a new status, a button of type button is invoked and calls 2 things(a pop-up cor credentials and a function for XMLHttpRequest).

```
function a(url){

try {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (req != null) {
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.onreadystatechange = getData;
            req.send();
        } else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    } catch (e) {       
        alert("Error");
    }
}

function getData(){

if(req.readyState == 4){

      ...some code
    }
}
```

After entering credentiols and click on ok, the latest status should be updated. This is working fine in firefox and chrome. Also the only time the status updates on IE is when the browser was closed then opened.

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: I'm Using IE10. This seems to work on IE8

Comment: Use this link.It may help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx